# My (U.S.) son will be studying in India for the next two years. Can he keep his U.S. cellphone number?

Tags: india

My son currently gets cell service in the U.S. via an AT&T Wireless family plan. He will spend the next two years in India. AT&T Wireless provides international service for $10/day (!). Is there a reasonable way for an American to use a cell phone with an American cell phone number in India?

Comment: [Google Voice](https://abroadpurpose.com/how-to-keep-your-mobile-phone-number-while-moving-abroad/) might be a viable option, though if I understand correctly it would mean that calls to & from the US number would only be accessible via a data connection.  This may or may not be viable depending on how reliably your son will be able to access WiFi or cellular data (and how much it will cost.)

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert wifi is too limiting. The best solution I've found so far would be to switch our U.S. coverage to T-mobile, as they offer global coverage at reduced speed with no additional cost (at higher monthly rates than we pay AT&T today, but not $10/day more).

Comment: @littleadv mostly data. some voice.

Comment: For data he'd be much better off getting a local subscription.

Comment: @littleadv If I were optimizing only for price, I'd be there with you, but I'm trying to keep his existing number if possible.

Comment: For TMobile - they provide this, but they also have an explicit callout in the T&C that the phone number should be used predominantly in the US. It is for travelers, not foreign residents.

Comment: I *think* Google Voice will work with cellular data as well, so he wouldn't strictly be tethered to Wifi with that.  If that's correct, he could get a local smart phone with a data plan and still make & receive calls to his US number.  But I've never used the service and don't know for sure if this will work, hence this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Google Voice will not work with cellular data from my experience

Answer (score -1):

He can. But he will pay for his US number in one month might be sufficient for 2 years if he gets a local number. If he wants to call international, use Rebtel ($10/month).